# Aquamacs startup dimensions

Tags: mac, emacs

For Aquamacs (emacs), how can I configure the size of the window when it starts? (E.g. have it always start fullscreen, or better - exactly half of the screen.)

Comment: +1 for realizing that half the screen is a better size for an editor than fullscreen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should customize the variables "default-frame-alist" and "initial-frame-alist" via ellisp in your init.el file or through M-x customize.

See the fine manual: *29.3.2 Initial Frame Parameters*

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Frame-Parameters

For example, to set frames to half the width and height of a 1280 x 800 display:

```
(setq default-frame-alist (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(width . 640)))
(setq default-frame-alist (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(height  . 400)))
```